# how to find the value of net salary in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztI16.png   the variable ns in the image is making problem and not giving the result needed plz suggest the proper way of writting it .

Comment: Code available only in external resources are not allowed in StackOverflow. Please post relevant code snippets in the question itself.

Comment: Keep in mind that Javascript calculations will give strange reults if you're using float numbers. It is good practice to view the value of variables on code lines. For example, this will **not** result in "1". `var x = (1.1 + 2.2) / 3.3; alert(x);`

Answer (score 0):

The code image you posted has some problems:

- **y** is not checked for being a number (the input allows strings!)
- I don't see code processing the input (like the input with ID **a**)

So, it seems that your code logic works, but some small things need fixing.

```js
const salaryInput = document.getElementById("a")
salaryInput.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  var x, y;

  x = document.getElementById("n").value;
  // checking whether y is a number - if not, treat it as 0
  y = isNaN(document.getElementById("a").value) ? 0 : Number(document.getElementById("a").value);

  var TA = 0.20 * y;
  var DA = 0.15 * y;
  var HRA = 0.50 * y;
  var PF = 0.20 * y;
  var NS = y + TA + DA + HRA + PF

  // rounding values with toFixed()
  document.getElementById("T").value = TA.toFixed(2)
  document.getElementById("D").value = DA.toFixed(2)
  document.getElementById("H").value = HRA.toFixed(2)
  document.getElementById("P").value = PF.toFixed(2)
  document.getElementById("NE").value = NS.toFixed(2)
})
```

```html
<label for="n">NAME: <input id="n" type="text"></label><br />
<label for="a">BASIC SALARY: <input id="a" type="text"></label><br /><br />

<label for="T">TA: <input id="T" type="text" readonly></label><br />
<label for="D">DA: <input id="D" type="text" readonly></label><br />
<label for="H">HRA: <input id="H" type="text" readonly></label><br />
<label for="P">PF: <input id="P" type="text" readonly></label><br />
<label for="NE">NS: <input id="NE" type="text" readonly></label>
```

Please note that the snippet above is on no way a "good code" - I just formatted it to use elements you might find similar to your code. Please note that I used `<label>` instead of `<span>` to wrap input fields.